# Japanese input doesn't work on 20.04

Tags: ibus, japanese, mozc

On lubuntu 20.04, ibus-daemon doesn't start at beginning of any session. If start it on the cli, everything seems to work

```
ps ux |grep ibus


alain       1771  0.1  0.3 272376 25904 pts/1    Sl   23:06   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-extension-gtk3
alain       1773  0.0  0.0 240232  7388 ?        Sl   23:06   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-portal
alain       1811  0.0  0.1 313096 11968 pts/1    Sl   23:06   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus-mozc/ibus-engine-mozc --ibus
alain       1832  0.0  0.0 166584  7024 pts/1    Sl   23:06   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-engine-simplealain       1765  0.0  0.1 314828  8548 pts/1    Sl   23:06   0:00 ibus-daemon
alain       1769  0.0  0.0 240408  7476 pts/1    Sl   23:06   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
alain       1770  0.2  0.6 405192 53000 pts/1    Sl   23:06   0:01 /usr/libexec/ibus-ui-gtk3

`
```

On the tray, I can choose Mozc as input method and in mozc hiragana or katakana the corresponding icons shows up but no conversion is done. French accentuated characters that usually can not be typed directly do appear correctly, as if the conversion engine was not running.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: My primary system has all those automatically run (it's on *hirsute*), but yeah they aren't running on a *focal* system I started... will try and investigate (using a *Lubuntu* tag may have made this easier to find; or keep track of should I lose it)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I am not sure what's wrong with your Lubuntu and I don't have that desktop for now, but I assume the Japanese language is not installed fully. Probably many other necessary packages should be installed. From the other users struggled with Lubuntu and Japanese found [this article](https://kinakoankon.net/ubuntu-20-04-japanese-input-ibus-fcitx-mozc/) is useful.

Comment: if you select "*Ibus Preferences*" in the Preferences menu, it'll will notice it's not running, ask if you want to start it, then provide instructions how to make that automatic on subsequent logins.  Have a look :)   *Note: being started that way (by LXQt) it won't take effect until login, ie. won't help with your use of `sddm` pre-login*

Comment: Further note:  Lubuntu uses `fcitx` as it's input method by default (not ibus), and the two (ibus & fcitx) can *fight* and interfere with each other (ie. *neither work very well*), so trying to use `fcitx` maybe a better alternative (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.1/fcitx.html  but you'll need to add `fcitx-mozc` as it's not installed by default to use mozc -- suggested by @wxl

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It works now!

Comment: I had to install fcitx-mozc, to modify .pam_environnement to add the needed modifiers and then to choose mocz (and NOT Japanese keyboard) in the input method. 
Thanks again for you help

Comment: Please write up what you did (inc. anything you found useful, inc. links) so it may benefit other users.

Comment: I wrote it in the comment you've just responded. Modified the original post if this is what was expected.

Comment: No, please answer in the "*Your Answer*" section below.  This is a question & answer site (not a forum), so Questions are closed by a valid answer, currently this question has no answer (*accepted or not*).  You can accept your answer after a time..

Answer (score 2):

I had to install fcitx-mozc, to modify .pam_environnement to add the needed
variables :

```
GTK_IM_MODULE DEFAULT=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE  DEFAULT=fcitx
XMODIFIERS    DEFAULT=\@im=fcitx
```

and then to choose mocz (and NOT Japanese keyboard) in the input method.

Thanks to all who helped.